# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(/*([^*]|[\r\n]|(*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))**+/)|(//.*)/: Nothing to repeat

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation, regex-greedy

I am getting error while constructing new RegExp(..) in javascript

my regular expression is to eliminate all the comments in the code.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(/*([^*]|[\r\n]|(*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))**+/)|(//.*)/: Nothing to repeat
```

my code is :

```
this.commentRegex = new RegExp('(/\*([^*]|[\\r\\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\\r\\n])))*\*+/)|(//.*)', 'gi');
```

kindly let me know the issue.

Comment: Why is this tagged as java?

Comment: What is `**+` supposed to mean? Why are you using `new RegExp` instead of a regexp literal?

Comment: @torazaburo this is typo mistake forgot to add one \ infront of star. you can observe in my code is:....  in the above

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you regex is correct, you need to prefix `/` with a `\`.

You final regex could look like:

`const regex = /(\/\*([^*]|[\\r\\n]|(\*+([^*\/]|[\\r\\n])))*\*+\/)|(\/\/.*)/g;`

Comment: beat me to it. :p to check your regexes, you can use: https://regex101.com and make sure you're using javascript (https://regex101.com/r/MCZjVG/1)